# Update Data from notion Database page to Google by App script

Tags: notion-api

I Try to run this script in google sheet to get update data from notion Database

```
function updatePage() {
let token = 'secret_hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh';
let pageId = '77777777777777777777777777777777';
let props = {
  "properties": {
    "[The Property Name]": {
     //in the case of a text field:
      "rich_text": [{
        "text": {
          "content": "[The New Value!]"
}}]}}};
let options = {
  "method": 'patch',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Notion-Version": "2022-02-22",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
  },
  "payload": JSON.stringify(props),
  "redirect": "follow"
};
  let url = 'https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/'+pageId;
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(response.getContentText()));
}
```

when I run it keep show error

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.notion.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: {"object":"error","status":404,"code":"object_not_found","message":"Could not find page with ID: 77777777-7777-7777-7777-777777777777. Make sure th... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

I get the page ID from Share URL

[https://terrific-barnacle-42j.notion.site/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?v=```77777777777777777777777777777777```](https://terrific-barnacle-42j.notion.site/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?v=%60%60%6077777777777777777777777777777777%60%60%60)

the page still existed I have try the api url

https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/77777777777777777777777777777777

it's return with

`{"object":"error","status":401,"code":"unauthorized","message":"API token is invalid."}`